# Where does the "mm" come from in GTKmm, glibmm, etc

Tags: c++, open-source, coding-standards, binding

I understand that the "mm" suffix [in various GTK-associated C++ binding libraries] *means* "minus minus," but where exactly does it come from?

I understand that there is a *programming language* called "C--," but if there were bindings (and I'm pretty sure I've seen some), they would be suffixed "--".

TL;DR: **Is there some page on [gnu.org](http://www.gnu.org/) that explains the "mm" suffix in various C++ bindings or is it just a *de facto* standard adopted by the open source community with no reasoning behind it?**

Comment: Voices are that `--` originally came from the strongly opinionated view that C was a superior language and C++ was just a necessary evil. It was then changed in `mm` for the reasons stated in @Stephen's answer.

Comment: "Voices are"? We're going to need a much better citation than that. It could just as easily be suffixed `--` because it _subtracts_ so much of the boilerplate tedium associated with using plain C `gtk`/`glib`. I'm very impressed by what they managed to do with C, but let's not pretend it looks nice. But until someone provides a proper explanation, my guess is no better than yours - although at least I properly qualified it as a guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [gtkmm's documentation:](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/unstable/sec-gtkmm.html.en)

> gtkmm was originally named gtk-- because GTK+ already has a + in the name. However, as -- is not easily indexed by search engines the package generally went by the name gtkmm, and that's what we stuck with.

Comment: This surface explanation is so easy to find that a much better question would have been why they originally used `--`. But, alas, I've not seen one (and "Voices are" doesn't cut it).